# can't navigate to another screen react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using react native with axios. When I click login in button it should redirect to Homescreen but it's not working. when I replace it with Privatescreen(); with alert('successfully logged in.'); it's giving successfully logged in msg but with privatescreen(); its giving 'Invalid username or password' msg. here is my code for handleLogin in login.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios  from 'axios';
import PrivateScreen from './getonAuthscreen';
    handleLogin = () => {
          const{ username, password } = this.state;
          if(username && password){
            axios
            .post('http://192.168.X.X:3000/user/login', {
              username,
              password,
            })
            .then(response =>{
               PrivateScreen();
        }).catch (()=>{
          alert('Invalid Username or password.');
        });
        // return alert('you may pass');
        }else{
        alert('Please check username and password correctly.');   } };
```

here is code for homescreen.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,Text
} from 'react-native';



class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome to the app!',
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
      <Text>TESTSTST</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }


}
export default HomeScreen;
```

and Code for getonAuthscreen.js

```
   import { createSwitchNavigator, createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen';

// Implementation of HomeScreen, OtherScreen, SignInScreen, AuthLoadingScreen
// goes here.

const startSingleScreenApp = createStackNavigator(
  { HomeScreen: HomeScreen,
   }
   );
//const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({ SignIn: SignInScreen });

export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    App: startSingleScreenApp,
  },

));
```

Comment: when you call privatescreen() it will throw error and catch block will alert 'Invalid username or password' msg, because privatescreen() is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow Auth flow from react-navigation.
[Example](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html)

```
export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    App: AppStackNavigator,
    Auth: AuthStack,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Auth',
  },
));
```

`this.props.navigation.navigate(userToken ? 'App' : 'Auth');`